# Excel program inserting in one column but not the one next

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a form that has two separate sections side by side in Excel

```
#  name    info info
```

then next to that is same  type column
 and they are numbered starting on the left side down the page and then it continues on the right side column....my problem is if I insert a row it adds a row to both sides.  So I would have info on Column one and blanks on column two.
Its in alphabetical order so if I want to add someone with a B name without adding to the right column...how do I do that???Thanks

Comment: Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually select just the four cells for the new data, then right-click > Insert. You will see a dialog where you can tell Excel to shift the existing cells down if you don't want to insert an entire row.

Mind you that unlike Word, Excel is not meant to layout data in a multiple column layout and if you need data to break into the second layout column, then you will need to do that manually with this approach.

Entering data this way is not the best architecture.